# c++ Funtion override Error c2504 base cass undefined

Tags: c++, overriding

I'm having a problem where i try to override a class but its giving me a error that the base class is undefined and illegal member initialization.

C2504   'PSVDicomObjectUniverse': base class undefined
C2614   'Derived1': illegal member initialization: 'PSVDicomObjectUniverse' is not a base or member

Here is my override code

```
#include...
...

class Derived1;
class Derived1 : public PSVDicomObjectUniverse
{
public:
    Derived1(
        PSVAssociation* assoc,
        PSVPrinterBackEnd& backend,
        DiDisplayFunction* displayFunction,
        OFConfigFile& config,
        PSVCentralClient& client) : PSVDicomObjectUniverse(
            assoc,
            backend,
            displayFunction,
            config,
            client) {}
private:
    Derived1(const Derived1& source);
    Derived1& operator=(const Derived1& source);
};
```

Here is the original funtion

```
class PSVDicomObjectUniverse;
class PSVDicomObjectUniverse
{
public:
    PSVDicomObjectUniverse(
        PSVAssociation *assoc,
        PSVPrinterBackEnd& backend,
        DiDisplayFunction *displayFunction,
        OFConfigFile& config,
        PSVCentralClient& client);
private:
    PSVDicomObjectUniverse(const PSVDicomObjectUniverse& source);
    PSVDicomObjectUniverse& operator=(const PSVDicomObjectUniverse& source);
};
```

[Complete code of my override class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyT7.png)

[Code of default class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meHUy.png)

[Code of my main includes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8L8L.png)

Example of my main

```
#include "DcmPrintFuntionsExtra.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    do something...
}
```

My Override funtion (DcmPrintFuntionsExtra.h)

```
#pragma once

#ifndef DCMPRINTFUNTIONSEXTRA_H
#define DCMPRINTFUNTIONSEXTRA_H

#include "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h"    /* for Operating System configuration */

 // forward declarations
class Derived1;
class OFConfigFile;
class PSVAssociation;
class PSVCentralClient;
class PSVPrinterBackEnd;
class DiDisplayFunction;
class PSVBasicFilmSession;
class PSVPresentationLUT;

#include "dcmtk/dcmnet/dicom.h"       /* for DIC_US */
#include "dcmtk/dcmprint/psvlist.h"   /* for PSVDLList */
#include "dcmtk/dcmprint/psvdic5.h"   /* for PSVDicomStringUI */
#include "dcmtk/dcmprscp/psvsop.h"    /* for PSVSOPinstance */

/**
 * DICOM print management SCP object agent
 *
 * The DICOM service class provider (SCP) receives messages for objects
 * it contains. The messages trigger operations (methods) on these objects
 * and result in return messages which inform the service class user (SCU)
 * about the results of the operation. This class is the central
 * agent that knows about all network visible objects and which dispatches
 * the messages to the objects.
 */
class Derived1 : public PSVDicomObjectUniverse
{
public:
    Derived1(
        PSVAssociation* assoc,
        PSVPrinterBackEnd& backend,
        DiDisplayFunction* displayFunction,
        OFConfigFile& config,
        PSVCentralClient& client) : PSVDicomObjectUniverse(
            assoc,
            backend,
            displayFunction,
            config,
            client) {}
private:
    Derived1(const Derived1& source);
    Derived1& operator=(const Derived1& source);

};

#endif
```

The original class

```
#ifndef PSVDIC8_H
#define PSVDIC8_H

#include "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h"    /* for Operating System configuration */

// forward declarations
class PSVDicomObjectUniverse;
class OFConfigFile;
class PSVAssociation;
class PSVCentralClient;
class PSVPrinterBackEnd;
class DiDisplayFunction;
class PSVBasicFilmSession;
class PSVPresentationLUT;

#include "dcmtk/dcmnet/dicom.h"       /* for DIC_US */
#include "dcmtk/dcmprint/psvlist.h"   /* for PSVDLList */
#include "dcmtk/dcmprint/psvdic5.h"   /* for PSVDicomStringUI */
#include "dcmtk/dcmprscp/psvsop.h"    /* for PSVSOPinstance */

class DCMTK_DCMPRSCP_EXPORT PSVDicomObjectUniverse
{
public:
  /**
   * @param assoc the association over which the return messages will be sent
   * @param backend the print server back end which will do the printing
   * @param config the configuration file facility
   * @param client the object that will provide unique object UIDs and other
   *        information that must be kept common on a multiprocess server
   */
  PSVDicomObjectUniverse(
    PSVAssociation *assoc,
    PSVPrinterBackEnd& backend,
    DiDisplayFunction *displayFunction,
    OFConfigFile& config,
    PSVCentralClient& client);

...
...

private:
  /* undefined */ PSVDicomObjectUniverse(const PSVDicomObjectUniverse& source);
  /* undefined */ PSVDicomObjectUniverse& operator=(const PSVDicomObjectUniverse& source);
};
#endif
```

Comment: [Coundn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V8xFNzdl9ghXLHj5). Maybe lack of required `#include` or circular dependency problem? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My guess is a circular include loop where 2 or more headers include each other forming a loop. With that said  I am confused at the current example with the use of forward declarations.

Comment: @drescherjm even with me only including that header in my main it throws the same error

Comment: Your actual code certainly has a problem, but the part you have shown has not. Mike's link show that it compiles fine. **Please show a [mre]**.

Comment: I updated the question with prints of the code. If u want the full example of the code written pls tell me.

Comment: I added the raw code to my question